# How to cancel tap on link in UITextView when finger moves?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView with a link(see below code). When I touch DOWN on that link, the link text will be selected. And when I touch UP on that link, the link will open with Safari. It's works fine.

But, I want to cancel this behavior when I move finger after touch DOWN. Can I to do that?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITextView* txt = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    txt.text = @"some text. http://www.google.com/ some text.";
    txt.editable = NO;
    txt.scrollEnabled = NO;
    txt.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
    [self.view addSubview:txt];
}
```